# Fragment: Programmatically create view for xml to fill

Tags: android, xml, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

Is there a way to create a new layout that you can then have your XML inflate?

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle icicle){

            one_third = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list3);

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            String width = "" + dm.widthPixels;

            int WIDTH;
            int SIZE;

            SIZE = Integer.parseInt(width.toString());

            WIDTH = (SIZE / 3); 

            one_third.setMinimumWidth(WIDTH);

    View homeselect = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listelements, container, false);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.start_row, R.id.label, views));
    return homeselect;

}
```

I'm trying to take this bit of code in the fragment and here is where I want to have the new layout be created. I want to give it the **width** of the value **WIDHT** and then have my xml fill that.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not really about Fragment.  The API here is just providing the part of the view hierarchy that the Fragment manages.  All layout is based around the view hierarchy.  You *do* *not* do your layout here, because you don't even know the space in which to do the layout.

The correct answer then is the same any time you are using the view hierarchy: participate in the regular layout flow through onMeasure() and onLayout().  If the standard layout managers won't do what you want, you can implement your own special subclass of ViewGroup that does your desired layout based on the size it gets.

Comment: So this sounds good and like it will do what I want but I'm like uber noob and have no clue how to do it. Haha. 

Would this allow me to call a layout inside of the XML instead and set it's values? and if so how is this done? Thanks,